# Idris totality check

Tags: idris, totality, idris2

I am compiling the following simple program using Idris2.

```
import Data.Fin

%default total

negate : {k:_} -> Fin k -> Fin k
subt : {k:_} -> Fin k -> Fin k -> Fin k
add : {k:_} -> Fin k -> Fin k -> Fin k

mult : {k:_} -> Fin k -> Fin k -> Fin k
mult FZ b = FZ
mult (FS a) b = add b $ mult (weaken a) b
```

However, the compiler spits an error:

```
Error: mult is not total, possibly not terminating due to recursive
path Main.mult -> Main.mult -> Main.mult
```

Isn't the recursive call on input `a` which is smaller than `(FS a)`? Why is the totality check failing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the compiler doesn't realize that `weaken a` is smaller than `FS a`, although I suspect that the problem is `weaken`.

You can work around it by *asserting* that `weaken a` is smaller than `FS a`:

```
module Misc

import Data.Fin

%default total

add : Fin k -> Fin k -> Fin k
add a b = ?add_rhs

mult : Fin k -> Fin k -> Fin k
mult FZ _ = FZ
mult a@(FS a') b = add b $ mult (assert_smaller a (weaken a')) b
```

Do note that under the usual definition of addition and multiplication on integers, the result could be larger than `k`. I assume your `add` implementation will take care of this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am interested in a solution without assert_smaller. I found a way to circumvent this, by avoid using `weaken` altogether.

Comment: @haskelllooksgreat that sounds good, feel free to post an answer to your own question! Self-answers are allowed and encouraged here.